# Include a Makefile as if I'm in another directory?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm working on a project that looks like:

```
rootdir/
  Makefile
  component1/
    Makefile
  component2/
    Makefile
  component3/
     Makefile
     lib1/
       Makefile
     lib2/
       Makefile
     lib3/
       Makefile
       Makefile.include
```

The first line of `rootdir/component3/lib3/Makefile` is `include Makefile.include`.

Now I want to write some unit tests for the code in lib3 in a new directory called `test`. So we have this structure instead:

```
rootdir/
  Makefile
  component1/
    Makefile
  component2/
    Makefile
  component3/
     Makefile
     lib1/
       Makefile
     lib2/
       Makefile
     lib3/
       Makefile
       Makefile.include
       test/
         Makefile
         test1.c
         test2.c
```

Inside of `rootdir/component3/lib3/Makefile` there's a rule that looks like:

```
$(LIB3_LIB): $(LIB3_OBJ) 
    $(CC) $(LIB3_OBJ) -o $@
```

So I figure the most natural way to write my tests will be to have a rule in `rootdir/component3/lib3/test/Makefile` that looks like:

```
%.o : %.c $(LIB3_LIB)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

and then with a little more footwork I'll be able to write a rule that catches all of my tests.

In order to achieve this, I figured I could `include` `lib3/Makefile` in `lib3/test/Makefile` like so:

```
include ../Makefile
```

but this errors:

```
test$ make 
../Makefile:1: Makefile.include: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `Makefile.include'.  Stop.
```

which makes me think that it's looking for `Makefile.include` in `lib3/test`, which is not the right thing to do.

I don't see anything in the `include` section of the [`make` docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) that addresses this issue, and I suspect that I'm approaching it the wrong way. What am I missing?

Comment: CRLF again? Did you check line endings?

Comment: Your observation is right. It tries to include a Makefile.inc from the test sub-directory. No problems with line endings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is right. It tries to include a Makefile.inc from the `rootdir/component3/lib3/test` sub-directory.

If you you just want to ensure that the library `LIB3_LIB` gets recompiled, you can use a sub-make which is called by `make -C ..` from the Makefile in `rootdir/component3/lib3/test`. This will call a make which has the parent directory as the current working directory, so that, the `Makefile.inc` can be found.

The `rootdir/component3/lib3/test/Makefile` would look like:

```
LIB3_LIB=../lib3.lib
%.o : %.c $(LIB3_LIB)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

# call sub-make
$(LIB3_LIB): FORCE
        $(MAKE) -C ..

# force sub-make
.PHONY: FORCE
FORCE:
```

One must use a phony target (named `FORCE` here), so that, the sub-make is always called. The compile rule still depends on the library name. Thus, the unit tests are only recompiled if the library has changed by the sub-make.

Each sub-make prints a message about changing the directory. If you want to get rid of this, add this line to the Makefile:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --silent #--no-print-directory
```